# Showing $\int_0^3\int_{4x/3}^\sqrt{25-x^2}f(x,y)dy\,dx=\int_0^4\int_0^{3y/4}f(x,y)dx\,dy+\int_4^5\int_0^\sqrt{25-y^2}f(x,y)dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Show that this integral expression is true:
$$\int_0^3\int_{4x/3}^\sqrt{25-x^2}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^4\int_0^{3y/4}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy+\int_4^5\int_0^\sqrt{25-y^2}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

I am not exactly sure where to start with this.

I have tried drawing a diagram, of which I am not even sure if it is useful. I just drew two graphs with rectangles that have side lengths corresponding to the limits. I got nothing from that.

All I notice is the flipped $dx$ and $dy$ on the right and that the upper limit for the $dx$ integrals on the right are the inverses of the lower and upper limit for the $dy$ integral on the left.

Here's the image I mentioned [image]

**EDIT:**
After receiving feedback I have updated by image to the following
[image]

Comment: You should be getting everything from the diagram. Please share what you drew.

Comment: I do not understand what you are drawing. If the lower bound of $y$ is $4x/3$ then you need to draw $y = 4x/3$ and if the upper bound of $y$ is $\sqrt{25-x^2}$, you need to draw $y = \sqrt{25-x^2}$ or $x^2 + y^2 = 25, y \geq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

The region described in the first integral is the one bounded by the line that can be seen in the picture below. So, if $(x,y)$ belongs to that region, $0\leqslant y\leqslant 5$. If $0\leqslant y\leqslant 4$, the the possible values for $x$ go from $0$ to $\frac34y$ (since $y=\frac43x\iff x=\frac34y$). And if $4\leqslant y\leqslant 5$, the possible values fro $x$ go from $0$ to $\sqrt{25-y^2}$ (since $y=\sqrt{25-x^2}\iff x=\sqrt{25-y^2}$). So, that equality holds indeed.

[image]